# Pushing Node.js files to AWS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, twilio, twilio-api

I have a node.js file that runs locally when I run it and it sends the user a text notification via the Twilio service. However, I'm trying to deploy it to my AWS Ubuntu server (EC2) so I can use it now on my actual website, but I'm not sure how to upload a local file to my instance like I did when I was following this tutorial (https://hackernoon.com/tutorial-creating-and-managing-a-node-js-server-on-aws-part-1-d67367ac5171) when I initially `mkdir server` and then cd into it which ultimately contained index.js, node_modules, and server file.

Now on my local folder, it also contains a folder called node_modules that currently has an express folder and a Twilio helper folder. So would I have to put the Twilio folder within the node_modules folder in AWS and is there a way to do this through the Terminal?

Additionally, I was curious if my app.js (Node) file would even function if my Twilio file is hosted on a GoDaddy server? I hope I made sense and any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you are looking to host Node.js scripts in an easy way, check out [Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/runtime/functions) too. (Note, I work for Twilio, just wanted to point it out.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rsync` command line utility (available on Linux, Mac, but also on Windows with Cygwin).

The way you'd use it is:

`rsync -e 'ssh -i YOUR_AWS_KEY.pem' -avh /path/to/your/local/folder YOUR_AWS_USER@YOUR_AWS_HOSTNAME:/your/remote/path`